# GCOV showing coverage for functions more than 100%

Tags: glib, gcov, gcovr

I built glib [link](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) with coverage.

`glib` uses the `meson` build system which requires the build to be generated in a separate directory.

I run `gcov` on each `gcno` file generated in order to get function coverage. I am interested in coverage broken down by function.

I ran into two problems:

1- For `gcno` files inside the build directory I get errors like

```
File '../glib/gcharset.c'
Lines executed:11.40% of 228
Creating 'gcharset.c.gcov'
Cannot open source file ../glib/gcharset.c

File '../glib/gstrfuncs.h'
Lines executed:100.00% of 1
Creating 'gstrfuncs.h.gcov'
Cannot open source file ../glib/gstrfuncs.h
```

I solved this by moving all the `gcno` and `gcda` files into a newly created directory in the root src directory of glib called `coverage_files`. This way this relative path for the c files would be work.

2- The second problem is the one I am currently stuck on. I get coverage for some functions exceeding 100%.

```
Function 'g_get_charset'
Lines executed:106.25% of 16
```

This is seen across many functions in different files and I can't figure out why or how this is even possible.

This is an example of the output for one `gcno` file.

```
 gcov -f gcharset.c.gcno
Function 'g_get_language_names_with_category'
Lines executed:0.00% of 26

Function 'g_get_language_names'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2

Function 'language_names_cache_free'
Lines executed:0.00% of 6

Function 'guess_category_value'
Lines executed:0.00% of 14

Function 'g_get_locale_variants'
Lines executed:0.00% of 6

Function 'append_locale_variants'
Lines executed:0.00% of 22

Function 'explode_locale'
Lines executed:0.00% of 19

Function 'unalias_lang'
Lines executed:0.00% of 14

Function 'read_aliases'
Lines executed:0.00% of 24

Function 'g_get_console_charset'
Lines executed:0.00% of 2

Function 'g_get_codeset'
Lines executed:0.00% of 3

Function '_g_get_ctype_charset'
Lines executed:0.00% of 14

Function '_g_get_time_charset'
Lines executed:0.00% of 14

Function 'g_get_charset'
Lines executed:106.25% of 16

Function 'charset_cache_free'
Lines executed:0.00% of 6

Function 'g_utf8_get_charset_internal'
Lines executed:58.82% of 17

Function '_g_charset_get_aliases'
Lines executed:0.00% of 3

Function 'get_alias_hash'
Lines executed:0.00% of 21

File '../glib/gcharset.c'
Lines executed:11.40% of 228
Creating 'gcharset.c.gcov'

File '../glib/gstrfuncs.h'
Lines executed:100.00% of 1
Creating 'gstrfuncs.h.gcov'

Lines executed:11.79% of 229
```